# .NET WCF service get JSON list of blobs

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, azure

I need to connect on my Azure storage (emulated) and get a JSON encoded list of files and directories stored inside.

I used this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) to connect to my storage, and I can list the content.

Now I want to know: is it possible to get the arborescense of my storage and get it as JSON array?

Comment: if you have been able to list the content what else do you want ? elaborate ? show the code you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from your code, you can create master and child POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects) - Containers and Blobs respectively. Then, iterate the containers and add them to the list. For each container, iterate through the blobs and add them to your container objects. Then [serialize these to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm) to get your representation.

OR

You can use the BLOB Storage REST API

```
 GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list&delimiter=/&maxresults=4
```

[More details in MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452233)

If you need to convert the XML result in to JSON, you can use Newtonsoft's library [Using Newtonsoft to convert XML to JSON](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/824374d0-a1a2-4edf-a09f-b0c34eaae180/how-to-convert-string-xml-to-json-in-c?forum=xmlandnetfx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JSonConverter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<Test><Name>Test class</Name><X>100</X><Y>200</Y></Test>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

            Console.WriteLine("XML -> JSON: {0}", json);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```